# Strip String after or before certain word vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, cut

I want to cut a string and take what is before a certain word and what is after a certain word.

Example:

```
Dim string As String = "Dr. John Smith 123 Main Street 12345"
Dim cut_at As String = "Smith"
Dim string_before, string_after As String

--cutting code here--

string_before = "Dr. John "
string_after = " 123 Main Street 12345"
```

How would I do this in vb.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use split() function or this

```
    Dim mystr As String = "Dr. John Smith 123 Main Street 12345"
    Dim cut_at As String = "Smith"
    Dim x As Integer = InStr(mystr, cut_at)

    Dim string_before As String = mystr.Substring(0, x - 2)
    Dim string_after As String = mystr.Substring(x + cut_at.Length-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx):

```
Dim original As String = "Dr. John Smith 123 Main Street 12345"
Dim cut_at As String = "Smith"

Dim stringSeparators() As String = {cut_at}
Dim split = original.Split(stringSeparators, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim string_before = split(0)
Dim string_after = split(1)
```